# Jquery Validate Minimum 1 checkbox checked

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have 3 checkboxes on my pages

```
<label class="checkbox-inline misspelling">
    <input id="mispelling" name="mispelling"  type="checkbox" value="1">
        Common Mispelling
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline altspelling">
    <input id="altspelling" name="altspelling" type="checkbox" value="1">
        Alternative Spelling
</label>
<label class="checkbox-inline altformat">
    <input id="altformat" name="altformat" type="checkbox" value="1">
        Alternative Format
</label>
```

I am just wondering using Jquery Validate, how can I ensure minimum one of them is checked ?

Comment: See [the `require_from_group` method](http://jqueryvalidation.org/require_from_group-method/) that's part of the `additional-methods.js` file.

Answer (score 0):

Use as ,

```
$(document).on('change', '.altspelling', function() {
    var count = $('.altspelling:checked').length;
    if(count <=0) {
        alert("You have not selected any one");
    }
});
```

or write on button

```
$("#buttonID").click(function() {
    var count = $('.altspelling:checked').length;
    if(count <=0) {
        alert("You have not selected any one");
    }
});
```